# undefined reference to `bf_malloc

Tags: c, unit-testing, debugging, memory-management

There are a few issues with the Unit test. When I go to run it, it gives several errors such as undefined reference to `bf_malloc', this continues for test_bf_free, test_bf_malloc, test_split_block, and test_coalesce_blocks.

**Here is the .c file**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h> 
#include "BestFit_MM.h"


int main() {

    printf("here\n");
    int i;
    void* ptr;

    // Initialize the heap list
    heap_list = (struct block*) malloc(sizeof(struct block));
    if (heap_list == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Unable to allocate memory for heap_list\n");
        return -1;
    }
    heap_list->next = NULL;
    heap_list->prev = NULL;
    heap_list->free = 1;
    heap_list->size = 4096; 

    // Allocate some memory blocks
    bf_malloc(512);
    bf_malloc(512);
    bf_malloc(512);


    dump_memory();
    printf("Free list:\n");
    dump_list(free_list);

    // Free all allocated blocks
    struct block* b = free_list;
    while (b != NULL) {
        struct block* next = b->next;
        free(b);
        b = next;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Allocate memory using the best fit algorithm
void* bf_malloc(size_t size) {
    struct block *b = NULL, *best = NULL;
    size_t min_diff = SIZE_MAX;

    // Find the best fit block
    for (b = free_list; b != NULL; b = b->next) {
        if (b->free && b->size >= size && b->size - size < min_diff) {
            best = b;
            min_diff = b->size - size;
        }
    }

    // Allocate the memory
    if (best == NULL) {
        // No block found, allocate a new block
        best = (struct block*) malloc(sizeof(struct block) + size);
        if (best == NULL) {
            printf("Error: malloc failed to allocate memory\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        best->size = size;
        best->free = 0;
        best->next = NULL;
        best->prev = NULL;
    } else {
        // Use the best fit block
        if (best->size - size >= sizeof(struct block)) {
            // Split the block if there is enough space
            split_block(best, size);
        }
        best->free = 0;
        if (best->prev != NULL) {
            best->prev->next = best->next;
        } else {
            free_list = best->next;
        }
        if (best->next != NULL) {
            best->next->prev = best->prev;
        }
    }

    return (void*) (best + 1);
}

// Free memory and coalesce adjacent free blocks
void bf_free(void* ptr) {
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the block header from the pointer
    struct block* block = (struct block*)ptr - 1;

    // Mark the block as free
    block->free = 1;

    // Add the block back to the free list
    block->prev = NULL;
    block->next = free_list;
    if (free_list != NULL) {
        free_list->prev = block;
    }
    free_list = block;
    if (block->prev == NULL) {
        free_list = block;
    }

    // Coalesce adjacent free blocks
    coalesce_blocks(block);
}

struct block* split_block(struct block* b, size_t size) {
    struct block* new_block = (struct block*) ((char*) b + sizeof(struct block) + size);
    new_block->size = b->size - sizeof(struct block) - size;
    new_block->free = 1;
    new_block->prev = b;
    new_block->next = b->next;
    if (b->next != NULL) {
        b->next->prev = new_block;
    }
    b->next = new_block;
    b->size = sizeof(struct block) + size;
    return b;
}

// Coalesce adjacent free blocks
void coalesce_blocks(struct block* b) {
    // Check the next block
    if (b->next != NULL && b->next->free) {
        b->size += sizeof(struct block) + b->next->size;
        b->next = b->next->next;
        if (b->next != NULL) {
            b->next->prev = b;
        }
    }

    // Check the previous block
    if (b->prev != NULL && b->prev->free) {
        b->prev->size += sizeof(struct block) + b->size;
        b->prev->next = b->next;
        if (b->next != NULL) {
            b->next->prev = b->prev;
        }
    }

    // Add the coalesced block to the free list
    if (b->free) {
        if (free_list == NULL) {
            free_list = b;
            b->next = NULL;
            b->prev = NULL;
        } else {
            struct block* cur = free_list;
            while (cur->next != NULL && cur->next < b) {
                cur = cur->next;
            }
            b->next = cur->next;
            b->prev = cur;
            cur->next = b;
            if (b->next != NULL) {
                b->next->prev = b;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Dump the contents of the heap
void dump_memory() {
    printf("Heap:\n");
    printf("Address\t\tSize\tFree\n");
    for (struct block* b = heap_list; b != NULL; b = b->next) {
        printf("%p\t%lu\t%s\n", b + 1, b->size, b->free ? "true" : "false");
    }
}

// Dump the contents of a block list
void dump_list(struct block* list) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    struct block* current = list;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->free) {
            printf("Block at %p, size %lu, free\n", current, current->size);
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

**Here is the .h:**

```
#ifndef BESTFIT_MM_H
#define BESTFIT_MM_H


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// Define the block structure
struct block {
    size_t size;
    int free;
    struct block* next;
    struct block* prev;
};

// Declare the heap list and free list
struct block* heap_list;
struct block* free_list;

// Allocate memory using the best fit algorithm
void* bf_malloc(size_t size);

// Free memory and coalesce adjacent free blocks
void bf_free(void* ptr);

// Split a block into two blocks, the first of size 'size' and the second with the remaining size
struct block* split_block(struct block* b, size_t size);

// Coalesce adjacent free blocks
void coalesce_blocks(struct block* b);

// Dump the contents of the heap
void dump_memory();

// Dump the contents of a block list
void dump_list(struct block* list);

#endif`
```

**Lastly here is the Unit Test**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "BestFit_MM.h"
#include <assert.h>

void test_bf_malloc() {
    void* ptr1 = bf_malloc(100);
    assert(ptr1 != NULL); // Test that bf_malloc returns a non-null pointer

    void* ptr2 = bf_malloc(50);
    assert(ptr2 != NULL); // Test that bf_malloc returns a non-null pointer

    void* ptr3 = bf_malloc(200);
    assert(ptr3 != NULL); // Test that bf_malloc returns a non-null pointer
}

void test_bf_free() {
    void* ptr1 = bf_malloc(100);
    bf_free(ptr1); // Test bf_free with a valid pointer

    void* ptr2 = bf_malloc(50);
    bf_free(ptr2); // Test bf_free with a valid pointer
}

void test_split_block() {
    struct block* b = (struct block*)malloc(sizeof(struct block));
    assert(b != NULL); // Test that malloc returns a non-null pointer

    b->size = 100;
    b->free = 1;
    b->next = NULL;
    b->prev = NULL;

    size_t size = 50;
    struct block* split = split_block(b, size);

    assert(split != NULL); // Test that split_block returns a non-null pointer
    assert(split->size == size); // Test that the split block has the correct size
    assert(split->free == 1); // Test that the split block is marked as free
}

void test_coalesce_blocks() {
    struct block* b1 = (struct block*)malloc(sizeof(struct block));
    assert(b1 != NULL); // Test that malloc returns a non-null pointer

    struct block* b2 = (struct block*)malloc(sizeof(struct block));
    assert(b2 != NULL); // Test that malloc returns a non-null pointer

    b1->size = 100;
    b1->free = 1;
    b1->next = b2;
    b1->prev = NULL;

    b2->size = 200;
    b2->free = 1;
    b2->next = NULL;
    b2->prev = b1;

    coalesce_blocks(b1);

    assert(b1->size == 300); // Test that the blocks were coalesced correctly
    assert(b1->free == 1); // Test that the coalesced block is marked as free
}

int main() {
    test_bf_malloc();
    test_bf_free();
    test_split_block();
    test_coalesce_blocks();

    printf("All tests passed successfully!\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Honestly, not really sure what I should even try. I expect an output from the unit test program with the printf statement at the end.

Comment: You need to link with the file that defines `bf_malloc`, but since it contains its own version of `main`, presumably you aren't.  If `bf_malloc` is meant to be a shared function that can be used by multiple programs, then you can't put it in a file that also defines `main`.  Split it out, then link with that new `.c` file.  Try to reason it out.  Each program needs to be lined with the functions it references.  And you cannot have conflicting function names in the same program.

Comment: You cant have two `main` functions in one project.